# With spring boot - can't get all the fields when querying on multiples tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, many-to-many

I'm trying to get information from both tables `model` and `user_model` but without success.

Tables have relations like these :

[image: Tables relations]

So i use HQL request to get this informations, here is the **request** :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);

    @Query("SELECT m, um.hasWriteAccess FROM Model as m, UserModel as um "
    + "INNER JOIN m.userModel "
    + "INNER JOIN um.user as u "
    + "WHERE u.username=:username")        
    List<Model> findModelsForUser(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

But i get duplicate information without the `hasWriteAccess` field? Hum, what did i forget ? I don't understand why it doesn't work while the same SQL query gives me the expected result...

Here is the result i get :

```
{
    "models": [
        {
            "displayName": "model1",
            "type": "type1",
            "description": "description model1",
            ...
            => Missing : "hasWriteAccess" : "1" 
        },
        {
            "displayName": "model1",
            "type": "type1",
            "description": "description model1",
            ...
            => Missing : "hasWriteAccess" : "1" 
        },
        {
            "displayName": "model4",
            "type": "type2",
            "description": "description model4",
            ...
            => Missing : "hasWriteAccess" : "1" 
        },
        {
            "displayName": "model4",
            "type": "type2",
            "description": "description model4",
            ...
            => Missing : "hasWriteAccess" : "1" 
        },
        ...
    ],
    "CENTRAL_GIT_URL": "xxxx",
    "CENTRAL_GIT_USER": "xxxx",
    "CENTRAL_GIT_PASS": "xxxx"
}
```

This is the **controller** with which I call the service that initiates the request :

```
@PostMapping("/authentication")
public  ResponseEntity<HashMap> process(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request) throws Exception {
    List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models = genericService.findModelsForUser( request.get("username"));
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("CENTRAL_GIT_USER", env.getProperty("spring.constant.git.central.user"));
    map.put("CENTRAL_GIT_PASS", env.getProperty("spring.constant.git.central.password"));
    map.put("CENTRAL_GIT_URL", env.getProperty("spring.constant.git.central.url"));
    map.put("models",models);
    return new ResponseEntity<HashMap>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It may be useful to show my entities. So I have **entity User** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "password" })
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7182498683194688448L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<UserModel> userModel;

    ... getters ans setters
```

And **entity Model** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="model")
public class Model implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1125066441066336997L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="model_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="model",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<UserModel> userModel;

    ... getters and setters
```

And **entity UserModel** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_model")
public class UserModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_model_id") 
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="model_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Model model;

    @Column(name="is_activated")
    private boolean isActivated;

    @Column(name="has_write_access")
    private boolean hasWriteAccess;

    ... getters and setters
```

Can you tell me where is my mistake ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this issue try to use 'distinct' in the query:

```
@Query("select distinct m from Model m join m.userModel um join um.user u where u.username = ?1")
List<Model> findModelsByUserName(String userName);
```

I think there is a bug in Spring Data JPA that leads to this situation. 
See my '[investigation](https://github.com/Cepr0/duplicate-parent-entities)' about this problem.

Also to workaround the issue try to use [Hibernate 5.2.12](https://github.com/Cepr0/duplicate-parent-entities/blob/29a07d51fe2aae71194af46ccfb185ece69eca78/pom.xml#L41) instead of 5.0.12 (by default)...

Answer (score 0):

With your help i modified my request like this :

```
   @Query("select distinct um from UserModel as um inner join um.user as u where u.username =:username")
    List<Object[]> findModelsForUser(@Param("username") String username);
```

And i get the result that i expected. Thanks